# ios - Calculate total image size in photos folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, storage, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to calculate total storage occupy by images in photos folder. I have write code as follows. I am able to fetch images successfully but this code has two problem -

1. if photos has over 7000 images, sometime app get crash. From, log I
   understand its for memory issue.
2. if i run this code multiple time, by back and forth, after 6-7 time the app get crash.

Any idea will be really helpful. I need to calculate storage for videos and songs individually

```
-(void)getPhotoSize{

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [_allPhotos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if (idx<_allPhotos.count&&asset) {

                [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
                    float imageSize = imageData.length;
                    imageSize = imageSize;
                    data.totalPictureSize+=imageSize;
                      _currentPhotoAsset=asset;
                }];
            }
        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try running with Instruments to see what is consuming the memory?

Comment: yes, while doing back and forth, i ran memory to check leakage. but unable to find out exact point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand you are dispatching the code instead of just running it, so I'm going to remove the GCD part from the sample below. You also need to run Instruments to check for leaks and to find out what is consuming the memory, but my guess is that you have an implicitly retain cycle by accessing an ivar directly. Try this:

```
-(void)getPhotoSize{
    for (PHAsset *asset in _allPhotos) {
        typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self; // weak reference to self to avoid retain cycle
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
            typeof(self) __strong strongSelf = weakSelf; // strong reference to make sure self exists until the block finishes

            float imageSize = imageData.length;
            imageSize = imageSize;
            strongSelf.data.totalPictureSize+=imageSize;
            strongSelf.currentPhotoAsset=asset;
        }];        
    }
}
```

I have also changed it to a regular for loop to avoid having nested blocks.

---

**Quick and Dirty Async Version**

```
-(void)photoSizeWithCompletion:(void (^)(float))completion {
    NSArray *assets = _allPhotos;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        float totalSize = 0;
        for (PHAsset *asset in assets) {
            [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
                totalSize += imageData.length;
            }];        
        }            

        completion(totalSize);
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
[someObject photoSizeWithCompletion:^(float totalSize){
    // use the totalSize
}]
```

This don't support cancelling for when the user hits the back button. But I'll leave it as homework to look into `NSOperationQueue` to make a cancellable async operation. Check Apple's documentation on [operation queues and concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: if i am not dispatch it is blocking my UI. thats why i tried to run this in background thread.

Comment: But if you `dispatch_sync` it still blocks your caller thread. Did you meant to use `dispatch_async`?

Comment: Just noticed that `data` seems to be an ivar too, so use `strongSelf.data` to access it and avoid the retain cycle.

Comment: yes, as large amount data need to calculate is time consuming. and i don't want block my UI. it takes almost 18-20 sec. pressing back and come again make the scenario more worse.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an quick and dirty async version. You should read much more about concurrency which isn't as simple as it sounds to get this problem done. I feel like the answer to the original question is there.

Comment: thanks. seems working also, i found another leakage at my code.

Comment: i have tried with 12,000 images it takes too long time to get total size that by occupy images. it take 58s. any idea how can i make it faster